# Would a burninate request for [copy] and/or [paste] be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

Copy/Paste don't really seem to be adding any value to questions they're used on - They're applied to questions using many different languages/frameworks and don't unambiguously help describe question content.

[copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copy)s description is:

> To copy is to create a duplicate of an object without destroying the original. Commonly seen in text editors that will let you copy some text and paste it somewhere else.

Looking through the questions on that tag some relate to copying something to the clipboard, some relate to copying within the file system, and others still ask about copying objects like lists. It doesn't seem to add any meaningful info to the post, given how broad it is.

Similarly, [paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paste)s description is:

> The paste tag is to be used for issues relating to the paste portion of copy/paste operations.

While this one is less ambiguous, scrolling through the tag I notice a lot of low quality questions, mainly tech support type ones. There are good quality questions but they relate to many different topics, from Bash to Excel to VBA to Rust, all of which have their own paste functions with their own behaviours. This one also doesn't seem to add any meaningful info.

I'm not trying to make this post a direct burninate request - Just asking whether the community thinks one would be appropriate for either or both of these tags, since I haven't raised one before.

Comment: Make sure to follow the process laid out in this [Q/A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) and esp. answer to all 4 points given in the first answer about burnination criteria. Compare your post with other burninate-requests which you find by clicking on the [burninate-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) tag.

Comment: Copy and paste are the two pillars Stack Overflow stands upon. I don't think we can afford getting rid of them ;-)

Comment: Can we stop [copy]-[paste]ing from Stack Overflow?

Comment: There is the [copy-paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste) tag, which I feel should be used instead of [copy]+[paste]. Though there is also [clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clipboard)...

Comment: I feel a disturbance, as if a million paperclips spoke out cheerfully offering to help, but then...

Comment: @kmdreko I feel like [copy-paste] has the same problem as [copy]+[paste] but just in one tag. Maybe [copy-paste] could be merged/synonymized with [clipboard] and [copy]/[paste] burninated.

Comment: If you'd want to create a burninate-request, remember, no two-fers. These should be handled separately, considerations for paste (nearly always related to pasting from the clipboard, probably on-topic but many related tags it may be merged with) and copy (very ambiguous) are very different.

Comment: I'm just popping in, so sorry if someone's already said this, but I think the combination of [tag:copy] and [tag:python] (or another language) would be useful — for people learning about the topic, for SO users looking for duplicate targets, etc., so if [tag:copy] gets burninated, please replace it with something like, say, `copy-object`, which could maybe be an alias of [tag:clone].

Comment: Cut/copy/paste is a highly fundamental concept worthy of some form of tagging. Perhaps the tags should be compressed to `[cut-copy-paste]` excepting cases not relevant to UI. I'm surprised this hasn't had any formal treatment yet on SO. The individual terms are kind of meaningless without other context, which suggests they're not individually worthy.

Answer (score 10):

The purpose of tags is to help search and find questions. I agree with you that there is not an instance where this helps anyone to answer or ask a question and get meaningful responses. If copy or paste is important for a rare question I think it can just be added to the header of the question.

I am of the opinion that these tags should be removed.

**Let's go through the criteria:**

1. *Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?*

   These tags are ambiguous and does not relate to what is being copy or pasted as well as the method and or language. Is it a deep copy, is it simply copy function or filesystem copy etc.
2. *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?*

   I have yet to see an example of that, and mostly, again, ambiguous.
3. *Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?*

   Not in my opinion, I think it detracts from the post more than it adds. By adding tag clutter and making meaningful things harder to spot of find.
4. *Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?*

   Mostly. Copy-paste in the file system has little to do with bash copy and paste. Deep copy of lists has little to do with either of the aforementioned as well.

Comment: "*I have yet to see an example of that, and mostly, again, ambiguous*" that's a bit overly harsh. Copying in various ways is definitely on-topic. Now, it's definitely *ambiguous* as there is a huge difference between, say, making a copy of some data, or "copying" the data to the OS clipboard. One could even ask questions about the copy *events* in UI controls - how to manipulate them. So, there are concept**s** that are on-topic. Yet, they are probably served better by more dedicated tags.

Comment: Thank you for [copy]ing and [paste]ing the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070).

Comment: @VLAZ I agree with you, I am overly harsh with copy and paste within the criteria. I am open to a discussion from the other perspective if someone has it. However, I do not think that even if I remove that point in the criteria completely from my argument it would not change my opinion on the tags. If anyone has found the copy-and-paste tags helpful, I would sincerely like to know. Because I can't think of such a case.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure burninate is appropriate, but a larger effort might be. The three words (cut, copy, paste), even in programming parlance, can have multiple definitions depending on the context. This alone makes the generic verbs inappropriate as tags for SO.

A larger effort would be to categorize (retag) all questions tagged with one or more of these individual word-tags with a new `[cut-copy-paste]` tag, if appropriate, or to remove the generic verb tag and potentially replace with some other more specific tag.

Comment: I wouldn't understand where you'd use [cut-copy-paste] where [clipboard] wouldn't be appropriate. [qt] [cut-copy-paste] means the same thing as [qt] [clipboard].

Comment: Hmm synonym maybe?

Comment: We wouldn't need a synonym since there is no cut-copy-paste tag. There'd be no reason to create one, because, again, it does the same thing as clipboard