# We should stop [copy]ing and [paste]ing tags

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Let's get rid of these tags. I don't really see an argument for keeping them. But let's take a look at the burnination criteria:

1. *Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied, and is it unambiguous?*

   It does describe question contents, but it is quite ambiguous. A list copy, clipboard copy/paste, file copies...
2. *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?*

   Sometimes. A list copy might be, but how to copy and paste wouldn't.
3. *Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?*

   Not really. I wouldn't search for [copy] if I were looking to answer questions about it.
4. *Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?*

   Again, it's ambiguous. Copy could mean file system copies, clipboard copies and what not.

I propose that [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copy) and [paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paste) be burninated, and that [copy-paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste) be merged/synonymized with [clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clipboard).

Comment: [Would a burninate request for \[copy\] and/or \[paste\] be appropriate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427119)

Comment: ... and how would we deal with questions, who are only `copy`-related, like "Why can't I copy a 5Gb object?", or only `paste`-related, like "I have copied information, but I only want to paste the value, not the entire formatting."?

Comment: @Dominique you say that as if it is impossible to ask such a question unless it has a copy or paste tag.

Comment: Oh my @zcoop98 that's quite meta :) Impopular Opinion: We should coming up with clever "funny" titles for tag burnination proposals. copyshrug.com

Comment: I don't think [the dupe target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427119/would-a-burninate-request-for-copy-and-or-paste-be-appropriate) is the same question. It's asking **if** a burninate request would be a good idea. This is an explicit burninate request, the dupe target is not. That's my opinion though, I have voted to reopen.

Comment: well, the other post seems to not just be about burnination but possibly other solutions.

Comment: Questions about how to copy or paste in code are definitely on topic.  I've answered such a question once, and I use the code I posted there daily.  But does it rise to the level of requiring a dedicated tag?  Probably not.  I can't imagine following such a tag for example.

Comment: I just looked at the [burninate criteria on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/343832) and they say *"**DO NOT** try for a two-fer - one tag per discussion"*, so this should probably be split up. Myself, I'm indifferent about [paste] but I feel strongly about [copy] (as I wrote in my answer). If I were you I'd spin off [paste] to a separate post, but leave a mention here.

Answer (score 2):

> 2. *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?*
>
>    Sometimes. A list copy might be,

A list copy absolutely is. Please disambiguate instead of burninating (or, before burninating? I'm not quite sure how the process works). For a list or other data structure, the tag could be something like "[copy-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copy-object)".

> I wouldn't search for [copy] if I were looking to answer questions about it.

True, but I would search for it if I were looking for duplicate targets.

---

Here are some questions about copying data structures that I think are aided by having a tag for it:

- [in language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic+copy)

  - [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/4518341)
  - [Why are copy constructors unnecessary for immutable objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2427491/4518341)
- [in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+copy)

  - [What is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17246693/4518341)

[clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clone) seems to be equivalent, but I'm not sure if there's any subtlety I'm missing.

- [in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+clone)

  - [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/4518341)

Comment: I don't see a scenario where I would be using [copy] to find dupe targets where [copy-paste] or [clipboard] wouldn't work. In addition, it's too ambiguous to use to find dupe targets. [copy] could mean a list copy, or an object copy, or a file copy, etc.,

Comment: @zurgeg Sorry, I was unclear about what I'm proposing so I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I **do** think that [clone] would be the same as a [copy-object] tag should one be created.

Comment: I would offer up [deep-copy] as another potential disambiguation

Comment: @kmdreko There's also [tag:shallow-copy], but I'd rather have an overarching tag.